# home networking, static ip with tp-link, subnet not matching destination address

Tags: networking

I tried looking at some tutorials and understand some networking basics to add a static IP for a media server and am having some trouble. Looking at my Mac that's connected to the router, I find that it's info is:

IP: 192.168.0.104 subnet: 255.255.255.0 router: 192.168.0.1

this is from the Mac-> Network screen. In the TP-link menu for the Archer C7, I try to add a static route with:

destination network: 192.168.0.123 (also tried 192.168.0.108) subnet: 255.255.255.0 default gateway: 192.168.0.1

and I keep getting the error message subnet mask doesn't match the destination address. I'm not sure how to fix this. I thought that in adding a static IP, you have the gateway set to what your router is. In my case 192.168.0.1. I kept the subnet the same since that's what my Mac connected to my router is. And then just gave a destination network address that isn't currently taken. This doesn't seem to work and my network knowledge isn't great. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Adding a static route to your router is not the same thing as adding a client with a static IP.  If all you're doing is configuring a client with a static IP you don't need to do anything on the router.

Comment: @heavyd But don't I need to tell my router to be aware of that static IP after I set my computer to a static IP of 192.168.0.123

Comment: No, as long as your on the same LAN the router doesn't need any special configuration.  The netmask you setup on the client (`255.255.255.0`) tells the client it can communicate with any IP between `192.168.0.0` and `192.168.0.255` directly.

Comment: @heavyd Ok that makes sense. But I need a static ip for a server so the outside world can see it according to a tutorial.

Comment: Ok, and thats fine.   You can still configure a static IP without making any changes on the router.  If you'r wanting your router forward a port to that server, look for a "Port Forwarding" section in your router config.